# Karma/Jasmine testcases failing due to ngIdle module

Tags: unit-testing, karma-jasmine, ng-idle

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngIdle due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngIdle' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

What is it that I am missing? If I don't include ngIdle module and remove the code for it's implementation then all my karma/jasmine tests are passing but with ngIdle included all of my 100+ testcases are failing and giving the above error. I have included `ngIdle` in `karma.conf.js` in this order

```
files: [
'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
'app/bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
'app/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
'app/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js',
'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
'app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
'app/bower_components/revolunet-angular-carousel/lib/angular-mobile.js',
'app/bower_components/revolunet-angular-carousel/src/angular-carousel.js',
'app/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
'app/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js',
'app/bower_components/ng-idle/angular-idle.min.js',
'app/bower_components/ng-grid/ng-grid-2.0.11.min.js',
'app/js//*.js',
'test/spec//*.js'
 ],
```

Below is my bower.json so you get idea about the versions I am using if that is related

```
{
  "name": "combo",
  "version": "0.5.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.3",
    "angular-route": "~1.3",
    "angular-touch": "~1.3",
    "angular-animate": "~1.3",
    "angular-resource": "~1.3",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.3",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.11.0",
    "revolunet-angular-carousel": "~0.2.2",
    "ng-grid": "~2.0.7",
    "ng-idle": "latest",
    "video.js": "~4",
    "highcharts": "~3.0.7",
    "jquery": "~2",
    "jquery-ui": "~1.10.4",
    "jqueryui-touch-punch": "git://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch.git",
    "angular-snap": "~1.4.1",
    "snapjs": "latest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.3",
    "angular-scenario": "~1.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "~1.2.10",
    "angular-touch": "~1.2.10",
    "jquery": "^1.8.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add **angular-idle.min.js** to your **karma.conf.js**.

```
files: [
  //Configs
  'config.js',

  'lib/angular/angular.min.js',
  'lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'lib/moment/moment.js',
  'lib/ng-idle/angular-idle.min.js',
  'lib/angular-moment/angular-moment.js',
  // ... another libraries
],
```

Comment: I have clearly written in my question that I have added 'app/bower_components/ng-idle/angular-idle.min.js', in my karma.conf.js and moreover ng-idle functionality is also working correctly in my application. It is only the karma tests which is failing.